# Throttle server bandwidth by percentage using Netty

Tags: java, netty

Is it possible to limit the server's global or channel bandwidth using Netty?

I can set explicit read or write rate limits via [GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler.html), but I'm trying to limit the server's global bandwidth to roughly half the available bandwidth. So if the server can upload at 8MB/s, I want to limit the uploads to roughly 4MB/s. And I want the server to adjust as available bandwidth changes; so if the server's upload rate decreases to 5MB/s (perhaps due to network utilization by other apps), then I want to limit the rate to apprx 2.5MB/s.

I've been playing with overriding [AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.submitWrite()](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.html#submitWrite(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20java.lang.Object,%20long,%20io.netty.channel.ChannelPromise)) and adding a delay based on the duration since the previous call, but the logic seems fragile and unreliable.

Any ideas on how to intelligently approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe QoS will be easier in this case. If you're using Linux try http://superuser.com/questions/309063/how-can-i-prioritise-network-bandwidth-on-a-per-application-basis

Comment: @kichik This is for a Java app that runs on Win/Mac/Linux.

Comment: It is very tough to know what the "available bandwidth" is. Things like the "link speed" are likely to be totally useless since on most systems the bottleneck is likely to be somewhere further down the line. Beyond that, looking at the aggregate bandwidth used by the application is not likely to be very accurate since it depends simultaneously on other applications on the host, and any bottlenecks that might be specific to whatever client is on the end of your TCP/IP connection.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Indeed. I think periodic sampling is the only way to guesstimate the real-world available bandwidth.

Comment: Indeed, but even there you have the problem I mentioned above: the throughput for a given interaction with a client depends not only _your host_, but also on the client(s) you are serving at the moment. If you sample when connected to a slow client, you'll get a speed much lower than the true bandwidth of your connection. Furthermore, sampling doesn't tell you the bandwidth even in the case the clients are faster than your host unless you are really saturating the connection with large, long transfers. Bursty traffic like html over http rarely gets up to max speed to TCP slow start etc.

Comment: Furthermore, all of the above only makes sense for outbound traffic. For inbound, you don't really have any control - the other side is going to send the packets at whatever rate it wants. So rate control is much more complicated than the outbound side (where you own the sending of the packets). If we are talking TCP/IP, you might be able to limit inbound speed by applying backpressure at the socket level, causing the other side to slow down, but this is complicated, and only works if you have a few clients and large payloads, not for the many client, small payload case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered using `GlobalTrafficShapingHandler` and periodically letting it go full throttle to figure out the server max bandwidth and then limiting it to half of that?

I would periodically do the following (on a schedule, maybe 1 second out of every minute)

- Increase the `setReadLimit` `setWriteLimit` to the max you would ever allow
- using the `GlobalTrafficShapingHandler`s `TrafficCounter` (via `public trafficCounter()`) to reset the count by calling `resetCumulativeTime`
- Make sure the interval of TrafficCounter is shorter or equal to the time you want to sample for. Change this using `TrafficCounter.configure(long)`
- Sample the TrafficCounter to get the server maximum bandwidth
- Modify the `GlobalTrafficShapingHandler` to use half of the bandwidth you just calculated

I think the above should give you what you want without being too fragile.

Comment: I'll award the bounty. This is more or less what I was attempting to do when adding a delay to AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.submitWrite() (except I was sampling every other request). I suppose the periodic sampling route is the best way to go. Thx!